# Decode only certain special character in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to decode just one special character while displaying in the html. Rest of the characters should just display as the plan text without decoding.

```
commentApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
```

For example, Please see the plunker below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eP7rMwDAtRRUcI75CzLG?p=preview

Here I just want to decode "Ω", but the other special characters should remain as the raw text in the html.
Is it possible?

Comment: Replace `&` with `&amp;` for the characters you don't want "decoded"

Comment: The problem is the special character can be anything as I am getting the data dynamically(It can be <div>Hello World</div> as well which I want to keep as is). I want to just decode "&Omega" and rest keep as text.

Comment: `<div>Hello World</div>` doesn't contain any `&`.... I fail to see the problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/eO3nz5M6BR7awZbvexzD?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/K88x12n1v3p4QPEYUI6g?p=preview. Please see this plunker. here I want to keep the html tags and the especial characters as text except for decoding "Ω".

Comment: "Keep as text". "Decode". I wonder if those words mean what you think they mean. Still `replace()` is probably what you're after, the question is just exactly what you want to replace. Or alternatively, look up `$sanitize`

Comment: What you want is probably something like `replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")` http://plnkr.co/edit/4au4epM6Hqt2KW6Ux2r1?p=preview